# Dependent JAR and Source JAR?

Tags: java, jar, terminology

What is a dependent JAR and what is a source JAR ? Why are they needed ?
I saw it in the sentence:
Dependent jars can be found in the libs folder and the corresonding source jars can be found in the libs-sources folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would depend on exact context. Most likely:

Dependent JAR - is a java library file the application depends on, common example would be third party libraries. It contains .class files.
Corresponding source jars  - java source code of the dependent jar packaged with jar utility. It contains .java files.

Comment: What is the purpose of having .java files packaged inside a JAR ?

Comment: @tortytorty The purpose is making the documentation of the classes/fields/methods available to the IDE, it will help while writing code.

Comment: okay, you mean auto-correct and auto-fill and stuff like that ?
eg. If i type HttpSe, then it will automatically add the remaining parts to make it complete - HttpServlet ?

Comment: @tortytorty You might want to examine source code, see javadocs, view code while debugging, create breakpoints... You cam do the same if you have zipped sources.